# SurfaceView colour differences between SurfaceView and View

Tags: android

I got two different elements, placed side by side inside a linear layout. One of the elements extends `SurfaceView`, while the other extends `View`.

Now, filling each element with the same solid color, shows they are rendered differently, the element which is extending `View` renders the color slightly darker than the other element.

I tried this both using `canvas.drawColor(int)`, and creating a paint and using `drawRect()` with the same paint in both elements.

Does anybody know whats causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the SurfaceView is not using 32bit color. Try  getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);